# Alternative cmd terminal?

Tags: windows, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows “cmd” Replacements](https://superuser.com/questions/35636/windows-cmd-replacements)

I'm looking for an alternative terminal for Windows like cmd. A very important thing is that it mustn't internally use cmd. I am looking for this because on some computers (cough at school cough) the windows cmd is "disabled", and I often need to use the shell to compile stuff there.

Comment: As per "Windows "cmd" Replacements" thread check out PowerShell.

Comment: Uhhm yeah. And I'm sure they would also allow you to install anything you want and compile "stuff"!

Comment: @slhck: I'm allowed to program at school since I already master all the content and am bored as hell (and I love programming). I have all the tools I need on an USB stick. But if I'm on a computer where the cmd is disabled it's hard to do anything.

Comment: Then, could you elaborate on what you need to compile? (Language, technology)

Comment: @slhck: Some C programs using GCC, and executing Python from the command line.

Comment: `cmd` is a shell (the terminal is Windows Console), and it's [easy to modify](http://goo.gl/rsqht) to ignore group policies.

Comment: @grawity: Wow I didn't know that. If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: So you have a portable C compiler?

Comment: @Mehper: That post only talks about replacing the console, but all answers still run the same `cmd` shell behind the scenes.

Comment: @slhck: MinGW and Cygwin are somewhat portable.

Comment: @slhck: Yes, previously I used [Tiny C Compiler](http://bellard.org/tcc/), but now I have a bigger USB stick I just installed [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) (very easy to install).

Comment: @grawity yeh "somewhat", that's why I asked :) (just out of curiosity)

Comment: `TCC/LE` is a compatible superset to `CMD`, and it's portable.